# matlab quadrature in a loop

Tags: matlab, numeric, integral

I'm trying to use matlab numerical integral functions,for example quad in a loop. But I also want to let matlab to calculate my integral for several integral limits:

```
p=1;
q=3;
for k=1:5
    a=0;
    b(k)=k.*10;
     integrand(k)=@(v)(v-a).^(p-1).*(b(k)-v).^(q-1);
p(k)=quad(integrand,a,b(k));
end
```

It really seems me clever:) but Matlab has no Idea:( 
Thank you for any help!
mg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem you have is that you're using `p` both as a parameter and also to store the results of your integration. So within the loop `p` becomes a vector, and then it can't be used as a power in the integrand. I'm not sure why, but I also seem to need to remove `k` as an index into `b` and `integrand`. But this code seems to work:

```
p=1;
q=3;
for k=1:5
    a=0;
    b=k.*10;
    integrand=@(v)((v-a).^(p-1).*(b-v).^(q-1));
    result(k)=quad(integrand,a,b);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could define integrand with an extra parameter, so

```
p=1;
q=3;
integrand=@(v,b)(v-a).^(p-1).*(b-v).^(q-1);  
for k=1:5
    a=0; 
    b=k.*10;
    p(k)=quad(integrand,a,b); 
end
```

but when I run it still gives an error:

```
??? Error using ==> power
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> @(v,b)(v-a).^(p-1).*(b-v).^(q-1)

Error in ==> quad at 76
y = f(x, varargin{:});
```

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do though ...